# Why does a column in a PowerShell table disappear if I sort in the opposite order?

Tags: powershell

I want to produce a table of process names and total CPU times sorted by total CPU time. The following works as expected:

```
ps | sort -p cpu | select processname,cpu
```

But if I reverse the direction of sorting as follows, the CPU time column disappears:

```
ps | sort -descending -p cpu | select processname,cpu
```

Why is this?

It seems that the CPU property is sometimes a Double and sometimes null. When I ran the first command, the first item had null CPU and the column does get displayed: for the second command, the first item has a Double-valued CPU and the column doesn't get displayed.

When the column doesn't get displayed it still exists! Using Format-List, shows it, for example:

```
ps | sort -descending -p cpu | select processname,cpu | fl
```

What is going on?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this

```
ps | sort -descending -p cpu | select processname,cpu | Format-Table -AutoSize
```

Comment: Well, adding the AutoSize option certainly shows the extra column, but I want to understand why, without that option, it's not shown for -descendind and is shown for the usual ascending sort.

Comment: @Omar, is it really not showing for you? When I run it in the ISE, the formatting does change, but if I scroll to the right in the output pane, I see the column.

Comment: @Rynant: Oh, I see what you mean now: the column might be beyond the visible part of the window, and autosize fixes that. I hadn't even thought of that. I'll check once I'm at my Windows machine again. Thanks!

Comment: @Rynant: You were absolutely right: the column was being showed, it hadn't disappeared, only it was outside the visible portion of the window. I feel like such an idiot. On the other hand, reserving 100 characters for a column with nothing more than 24 characters wide is surprising...

Comment: @Omar, when a formatting cmdLet (`Format-<Custom|List|Table|Wide>`)is not used, you can't really count on the output looking a certain way. Still, it does seem weird that the width of the column changes when changing the sort to `Descending`.

Comment: The reason for this is that formatting in PowerShell (especially automatic formatting) is strongly influenced by the first object in the output.  In your first example, you have two columns so they each get half the screen.  The first CPU value is $null, so the column is treated as strings.  In the second example, the first CPU value is a number, so the whole column is treated as numbers and right aligned (pushing everything to the right edge of the screen).  Make sure your buffer width is the same as your window width.  :)

Comment: @JasonMArcher: Thanks for the tip! I did have a bigger buffer than window.

Answer (score 0):

The properties of the first object in the result set determines the columns to be displayed. Any answer that forces the column into the first returned result will display the column for all returned results.

Comment: This still doesn't explain the behavior, I think: all objects have both a ProcessName and CPU property; when the first object has null CPU the CPU column DOES get displayed, but when the first object has a Double-valued CPU property the column DOES NOT get displayed. That's weird, right?